# php showing error even after the data has been inserted to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

In Php I am doing a file upload with some data insert
My form looks like this

```
 <form id="formID1" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="">'.$this->l('Add Store Type').'</label>
      <input type="text" name="store_type" />
      <label for="">'.$this->l('Upload Your Custom Icon').'</label>
      <input type="FILE"  name="custom_icon" id="custom_icon" />
      <input type="submit" name="store_config" value="'.$this->l('Add Store Configuration').'" class="button" />
    <form>

For uploading images I am doing a folder with 777 permission on it.


$uploaddir=dirname(__FILE__)."/storeconfig";
  if(!file_exists($uploaddir)) {
    mkdir($uploaddir, 777, true);
  }
   $tmpName=$uploaddir."/";
```

Now for inserting values I am doing this code.

```
if(isset($_POST['store_config'])) {
  global $uploaddir;
  $custom_icon_name = time().$_FILES['custom_icon']['name'];
  $allowed_extensions = array('gif','jpg','png');
  $path_info = pathinfo($custom_icon_name);
  if( !in_array($path_info['extension'], $allowed_extensions)) {
   echo "Incorrent file extension, Please Use png,jpg or gif files only";
      } else {
      if(mysql_query('INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'store_config` (`store_config_id`,`store_type`,`custom_icon`) VALUES ("","'.$store_type.'","'.$custom_icon_name.'") ')) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['custom_pin']['tmp_name'],$tmpName.$custom_icon_name)) {
         echo "Settings updated successfully";
        } else {
        echo "You Have Some Errors";
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Here the values are storing into the database successfully after doing click on button `Add Store Configuration` but still I am getting the error  `You Have Some Errors` which I have set in my form.It should show Settings updated successfully. Can someone tell me how this is error is coming?

Comment: move_uploaded_file is failing, it has nothing to do with database. might be permission problem.

Comment: Do you even know why you're adding error checking ?

Comment: This can be a permission problem, please have a look at the folder permissions and let us know the result.

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions for database access.  They're deprecated.  Use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: ohh..I got the error. I just made folder permission and it worked. But here I want to know as I have set 777 permission in my code then why I had to set the permission again manually?